# Complexity of a satisfiability problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, sat, np, polynomial-time

I would like the know the complexity of a specific satisfiability problem. I have a feeling it could be solved in polynomial time, but I am not sure about it. The problem is described below.

Given $n$ boolean variables $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and two types of clauses.

1. At most $n$ clauses of the form $v_a \to \neg v_i \land \neg v_j \land \dots$ where $v_a$ cannot be on both sides of the implication.
2. At most $n$ clauses of the form $v_a \lor v_b \lor \dots$ where any combination of variables is possible (but no negations!).

The goal is to satisfy all the clauses. I have a feeling this can be done using limited backtracking just like with 2SAT as described on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Limited_backtracking.

Comment: I think this is not a research-level question because the answer can be found in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem.

Comment: The "at most $n$" can be omitted (if you have too many clauses, pad with extra unused variables and then that constraint will be satisfied).  I don't believe this is covered on Wikipedia; if you believe that, please provide more specifics.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions the NP-completeness of one-in-three positive 3-SAT, which is straightforward to reduce to this problem (with the observation that the limit for clauses doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is NP-hard.

Here is a reduction from SAT.  Suppose you have a CNF formula $\varphi$ with variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  Add variables $x'_1,\dots,x'_n$ and clauses of the form $x_i \to \neg x'_i$ and $x_i \lor x'_i$.  For each clause in $\varphi$, we add a corresponding $\cdots \lor \cdots$ clause: e.g., if $x_i \lor \neg x_j \lor x_k$ is a clause in $\varphi$, then we add the clause $x_i \lor x'_j \lor x_k$.  Once you've added all these clauses, add up the total number of clauses; say you have at most $m$ of the first type of clause and at most $m$ of the second type of clause.  Now add unused variables $x_{n+1},\dots,x_m$.  The result is an instance of your problem with $m$ variables and at most $m$ clauses of each type.  Now $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff this instance is satisfiable.

Comment: $x_i\to\neg x'_i$ and $x'_i\to\neg x_i$ are exactly the same clause ($\neg x_i\lor\neg x'_i$). There is no need to include it twice.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, oops, fixed, thank you!